# Error while installing 'XD to flutter' plugin in adobe XD

Tags: flutter, plugins, adobe-xd

I have AdobeXD  installed in my machine. Now i want to use it for creating UI and then export it as flutter widget. For this, i need 'xd to flutter' plugin installed in adobe xd. I went to plugins->browse->XD to flutter->install and i am getting the following error.

[image: Error_image]

I am not able to figure out whether what is the issue with it.

Comment: Did you "See the help center"? Or maybe Google the error message?

Comment: Thank you so much for embedding the image.I couldn't do it. I checked google for answers and it said some changes in the folder structure, but i couldn't find that folder. And in the help center, they have mentioned all possible reasons for it.

Comment: I got it. The problem is solved. All I had to do was "Disable Antivirus Protection". Thank you for your reply :)